# Extending Django-admin's DateFieldListFilter for custom "Upcoming" filter

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I am trying to add a custom "Upcoming" filter to the Django Admin DateFieldListFilter. It's really simple, just selecting dates after today. Building on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735191/how-do-i-extend-django-admins-datefieldlistfilter-class) i was able to extend Django's standard DateFieldListFilter into my own custom one as follows :

```
class MyDateTimeFilter(DateFieldListFilter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDateTimeFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        today = datetime.now()    
        self.links += (('Upcoming'), {self.lookup_kwarg_since: today.strftime('%d %B %Y')}),
```

It correctly displays "Upcoming" at the bottom of my filters, but clicking does not actualy filter the results. I do not know what's wrong with my syntax and I have tried many alternatives...

Your help is very much appreciated!

PS: I am using Python 3.5.2 and Django 2.0.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without jumping straight into this one, I have done exactly what you needed for a previous project:

In `filters.py`:

```
import datetime

from django.contrib.admin.filters import DateFieldListFilter
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class MyDateTimeFilter(DateFieldListFilter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDateTimeFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        now = timezone.now()
        # When time zone support is enabled, convert "now" to the user's time
        # zone so Django's definition of "Today" matches what the user expects.
        if timezone.is_aware(now):
            now = timezone.localtime(now)

        today = now.date()

        self.links += ((
            (_('Upcoming'), {
                self.lookup_kwarg_since: str(today),
                self.lookup_kwarg_until: str(today + datetime.timedelta(days=7)),
            }),
        ))
```

You want to add a few declarations to be used later (e.g., `today = now.date()`) and then you want to use the `self.lookup_kwarg_until` keyword argument, and have some time range as your lookup until date (for ease, I have used `today + datetime.timedelta(days=7)`, but you could quite easily configure this to whatever timespan you need.

Then you'd need something like this in `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from filters import MyDateTimeFilter

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ('published_at', MyDateTimeFilter()),
    )
```

***Disclaimer***: this worked on Python 3.7, Django 2.0*. Fingers crossed this works for you!

Comment: As a note, at least in Django 3.0 (I haven't tested on other versions), you should not initialize an instance of the filter in `list_filter`, instead passing the class as `MyDateTimeFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer,  it definitely pointed me in the right direction.

I was missing the _ in my syntax and I was trying to create my custom filter directly in the **admin.py** and not **filters.py**. Since I was not sure if you were refering to the Django source file **django.contrib.admin.filters.py** or a new created **model.filters.py** file, I tried both method, adding a custom filter and then importing did not work for some reason I had the following error code:

```
  TypeError: __init__() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'field', 'request', 'params', 'model', 'model_admin', and 'field_path'
```

It is like my *init* declaration is incomplete.

However, given I found Django filters's original source file, I was able to adjust Django's original code (which is probably not recommended, but harmless in my case) and it worked great. I was not able to extend the original filter, but to override it.

Comment: Hi Alain, yes I certainly wouldn't advise meddling with the core/base Django project ... use my extend method and you won't go far wrong! :) Can my question be marked as a suitable answer?